# Migrating CouchDB 1.x to 2.x using couchup Utility

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to migrate CouchDB 1.x to 2.x using "couchup" utility as suggested in https://docs.huihoo.com/apache/couchdb/2.1/install/upgrading.html. But I am not sure how/where to run the below commands. Please provide the step by step guide to migrate the databases from 1.x to 2.x.

Thank you

```
$ couchup list           # Shows your unmigrated 1.x databases
$ couchup replicate -a   # Replicates your 1.x DBs to 2.x
$ couchup rebuild -a     # Optional; starts rebuilding your views
$ couchup delete -a      # Deletes your 1.x DBs (careful!)
$ couchup list           # Should show no remaining databases!
```